# Why I am getting blank page on magento 2 orders print.?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

In my account pages when I click on print order I am getting a blank page with just order number and URL. What is the issue? Magento version is 2.1.8

[image: empty pdf]

Comment: I also facing this issue, any one have a idea what is the problem.

Comment: @ChiragPatel  its react.js issue . you should update magent 2.1.8

Comment: I am using magento 2.2.4

Answer (score 0):

We are facing a similar issue in 2.3.1. What I observed is window.print is getting called right after the page is ready instead of after complete page load. This is causing the issue. If we try after complete page load then it is fine. Hope this will help.

```
<script>
    require(
        [
            'jquery'
        ],
        function($) {
            $(function() {
                window.print();
            });
        }
    );
</script>
```